# How to install local library with pip to a conda environment using environtment.yml file?

Tags: python, pip, yaml, conda, environment

I want to set up an `environment.myl` file for a project's conda environment. I have a local package that I would normally use `pip install -e .` so I can work on the code locally. Is there a way to use pip to install this package with the env file?

I tried this based on something I found using install options with github links, but doesn't work.

```
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - /Users/me/projects/package/ --install-option="-e"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [the code shows](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/fd89e90b81b196f9aff6a3971b2730da85216aa7/conda_env/installers/pip.py#L17), `conda-env` will copy the entries in the `pip:` YAML list and place them into a temporary pip requirements file. Hence, you should follow [the Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/), namely,

```
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -e /Users/me/projects/package
```

A quick test on a local package for me verified that the package installed and shows up in `pip list -e`.

There is also [an `advanced-pip/` example in the repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/fd89e90b81b196f9aff6a3971b2730da85216aa7/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip) that illustrates some additional options.

Comment: is there a way to use `conda develop ~/path/python/proj` inside of the `yml` file? I currently run that seperately but that seems less nice than what your doing...? at least the  `conda env export > environment.yml` doesn't include that info.

Comment: @CharlieParker no, there isn’t. Conda does not assume `conda-build` is installed, and that is what defines the `conda develop` command.