# Conda refuse to install packages from requirements.txt just because of a few outliers, how to fix it?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, requirements.txt

I'm using requirements.txt to manage my python dependency:

```
six
tqdm
future
numpy
brine

scipy
matplotlib

# birdseye
shapely

git+https://github.com/tribbloid/jupyerlab-desktop.git#subdirectory=python
jupytext

# pyre-check
# deprecated

torch >= 1.2.0
# tensorboard
# opencv >= 4.0.0

# prototypes
git+https://github.com/pytorch/vision.git@v0.4.0#egg=torchvision
tb-nightly
```

My environment is a conda env on python 3.7. I was trying to use a few command to install these packages, but when I run:

```
conda install --file requirements.txt
```

I got the following error message:

```
$ conda install --file ./requirements.txt 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tb-nightly
  - //github.com/tribbloid/jupyerlab-desktop.git
  - torch[version='>=1.2.0']
  - //github.com/pytorch/vision.git@v0.4.0
  - brine

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

It appears that conda refuse to install any of them simply because it can't find 3 packages! (they are on PyPI) What's the point of this design and what should I do to fix it?

My end goal is to use conda if possible, and fallback to pip if they are only on PyPI, the entire process should be reproducible and fully automated.

Comment: Use an environment YAML file instead - it can handle both Conda and Pip package installs. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57835528/570918 . Otherwise, there is no way to selectively ignore packages that can't be resolved.

Comment: @tribbloid did you ever find a solution to your problem? I believe I have nearly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete offending packages from `requirements.txt`, run conda on the new `.txt`, then install non-installed packages via `pip` into your `Anaconda/pkgs` (or move them there manually post-install). Then, run `conda update --all` to ensure compatibility.

Worked for me for a similar instance.

Comment: I did that also did `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` but that didn't work - I still can't install my packages with conda and requirements.txt :(

Answer (score 1):

This works on Linux. Just install via pip in your conda environment, it won't complain about not finding the packages like conda.

- Run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This will install the packages in your conda environment plus all their dependencies.

Make sure to activate your environment and that you are running this command in the directory where your requirements.txt is i.e in terminal `cd` to wherever requirements.txt is.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to try only after installing keras and tensorflow via pip so I can't say 100% that it would've worked for those as well, but everything else in my req file (+50 modules) installed with this command on Win11 in Anaconda Powershell while in the active environment.

`conda install -c conda-forge --file requirements.txt`

I still don't know why I needed to do this.  Also, I tried another req file that I didn't have a problem with weeks prior.  It also failed as the OP states.  I don't know what I may have done (not done) to cause this.  Perhaps missing a conda update or server down.